# How to calculate the t test for each groups in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
salary_old<-c(100,200,300,400,10000,100,10,20,30)
salary_new<-c(200,300,400,500,230,240,30,40,50)
d<-as.Date(c('2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03'))
country<-c('USA','UK','IR')
id<-c('A','B','A')
data<-data.frame(id,country,d,salary_new,salary_old)
data<-data %>% arrange(id,country,d)
```

Then I want to calculate the T.test for the salary old and new for each group using loop or apply function to check if the p-value of each group is less than 0.001.

I wrote codes as follows:

```
    datlist <- split(data ,list(data$id , data$country) )
 datlist<-datlist[sapply(datlist, nrow)>0]

 results<-  lapply(
  1:length(datlist) ,
  FUN = function(x) {
   t.test(datlist[[c(x,4)]] , datlist[[c(x,5)]])
  })

x<-matrix(nrow=3,ncol=1)
for (i in 1:length(results)){
   x[i]<-results[[i]]$p.value
  x[i]<-(sum(x[i]<0.001))

}
```

I got the p.value for each group but I want to join this to the main data frame to know that how much is the p_value associated to  id/country/combination: Like the following out put.

```
id   country  p-value         status
A     USA      0.5417366       0
A     IR       0.4321609       0
B     UK       0.7066187       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to join all the results into one `data.frame` at the end of your operations. 
First you construct mini `data.frame`s for each t-test and then
`rbind` them.

You can use this:

```r
results <- lapply(
    datlist,
    FUN = function(x) {
      tres <- t.test(x[["salary_new"]], x[["salary_old"]])
      lt05 <- sum(tres$p.value < 0.05)
      data.frame(x[1L, "id", drop = FALSE],
          x[1L, "country", drop = FALSE],
          pval = tres$p.value,
          status = lt05)
    }
)

do.call(rbind, unname(results))
```

**Note**: Significance level at 0.05 as posed in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please tell me what is 1L in the data.frame that you created?

Comment: It just takes the first row of the split mini `data.frame` which indicates the first ID value or country name since they're the same for all rows per mini `data.frame`